# What would be the most efficient way to load data from database in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel-5, query-optimization

I have these tables in my database (PostgreSQL):

```
events(id, title, starts_at, ends_at, ...)
reservations(id, event_id, ...)
reservation_messages(id, reservation_id, ...)
```

And I have API call: `/api/v1/host/events` which must return a json array of events, but each json object in array must contain two additional fields `reservations_count` and `unread_messages_count`. Also I need only events that have not ended, which means `ends_at` column is greater than `now()`

I am thinking of the most efficient way to load these "count" fields.
Next query gives me desired result but I do not know how efficient it is:

```
$user->host->events()
    ->where('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->withCount([
        'reservations', 
        'reservationMessages AS unread_messages' => function($query) { 
            $query->where('seen', false); 
        }
    ])
    ->get()
```

And this will produce big query and there will be a lot of joins:

```
select "events".*, (select count(*) from "reservations" where "events"."id" = "reservations"."event_id") as "reservations_count", (select count(*) from "reservation_messages" inner join "reservations" on "reservations"."id" = "reservation_messages"."reservation_id" where "events"."id" = "reservations"."event_id" and "seen" = ?) as "unread_messages_count" from "events" where "events"."host_id" = ? and ("events"."host_id") is not null and "ends_at" > ? and ("events"."deleted_at") is null
```

Is there any more efficient way to load desired result, because I think this query will be very slow on database that has a lot of data in it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the query together using with() between your relationships for fast eager loading. And if you're concerned about database size and execution time, just count the records after you retrieve them in a collection and append a dynamic property with the count for reservations and one for unread messages. Working on Collections in memory is fast and spares you the DB queries.